# Иногда самопроизвольно отключается панель задач в Windows-10-64

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-10

Добрый день.

Есть ноутбук ACER Pentium четырехъядерный довольно новый (CPU N3540 покупал два  года назад). На нем стояла Windows-8 после покупки она проапгрейдилась до Windows-10-64 Home Edition. Все обновления стоят. НО! Периодически отключаются некоторые функции панели задач. Например, иногда перестает вызываться панель часов, и перестает по правой кнопки мыши предлагать меню задачи - запустить второй экземпляр, закрыть все экземпляры и т.д. После перезапуска машины эти функции восстанавливаются, но при следующем запуске опять могут отключиться. Раньше, сразу после переустановки Windows, такого не было. Последняя переустановка была примерно полгода назад. Глюки с панелью задач начались одну или две недели назад.

Вопрос:

1. Было ли у кого-то что-то похожее и как это лечить?

Спасибо

PS. Все-таки винда как глючила так и глючит что ты с ней не делай и какие новые версии не выпускай.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причин может быть много. Для начала советую создать нового пользователя на данной машине и понаблюдать, будет ли подобное с такой же частотой, что и под текущим пользователем. Если совсем нет, или наблюдаться будет реже, то стоит попробовать выполнить следующие команды по порядку:

Открыть powershell под администратором, выполнить команду:

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

Вряд ли, конечно, спустя два года на вашем компьютере какие-то программы до сих пор работают в режиме разработки, но попробовать стоит, благо деструктивных функций данная команда не несёт.

Далее, можно провести проверку и восстановление поврежденных файлов установленных пакетов.
Проверка:

```
dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth
```

восстановление:

```
dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

Однако, подобные ошибки могут быть связаны с неправильно удаленными программами, мусорными записями в реестре, аппаратными ошибками и т.п. Поэтому утверждать, что предложенные мною способы гарантированно решат вашу проблему, я не буду.

Comment: Проще винду переустановить, чем разбираться со всей этой ерундой. Тем более без гарантии результата. Но все равно спасибо за совет. Насчет аппаратных ошибок порадовало. Панель задач такое чисто программное явление и чтобы именно на нее действовал какой-то аппаратный сбой это маловероятно.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Это как раз легко: допустим, в трее у вас должна сидеть программа, связанная с каким-то железом, да пусть хоть консоль к видеокарте. При возникновении ошибок в её работе, связанных с железом, она легко может вызывать подвисания или даже вылет таскбара. Еще чаще такое бывает при проблемах с HDD.

Comment: [она легко может вызывать подвисания] Тогда, для начала, были бы проблемы с самой видеокартой или с диском. А этого не наблюдается.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Это если проблема касается непосредственно ввода-вывода. А если сервисных функций?